# Create nested json with c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, nested

I am able to create a flat serialized JSON string pretty easily with c#

My issue is I want to create a nested string like this below

```
[ { 
    title: "Yes",
    id : "1",
    menu: [ { 
        title: "Maybe",
        id : "3",
        alert : "No",
        menu: [ {
            title: "Maybe Not",
            id : "8",
            alert : "No",
            menu: []
        } ]
    } ]
},
{
    title: "No",
    id : "2",
    menu: []
}]
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Are you using JSON.Net library or a custom implementation? Check if the library can help - will save you a ton of time...

Comment: What are you defining as a *nested string* ?

Comment: @cWilk, You should post your code (expecting 1 or 2 lines) that shows what particular "pretty easily" way of creating JSON you pick.

Comment: return data from SP - created object  listItem[] li = new listItem[count] - returnString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(li); return returnString

Answer (score 17):

Are you using MVC 3? - Do something like:

```
return Json(myObectWithListProperties, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I use this to return complex C# objects that match the structure of the JavaScript objects I want.

e.g.:

```
var bob = new {
    name = "test",
    orders = new [] {
        new  { itemNo = 1, description = "desc" },
        new  { itemNo = 2, description = "desc2" }
    }
};

return Json(bob, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

gives:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "orders": [
        {
            "itemNo": 1,
            "description": "desc"
        },
        {
            "itemNo": 2,
            "description": "desc2"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: A bit more nesting for fun:

```
var bob = new {
    name = "test",
    orders = new [] {
        new  { itemNo = 1, description = "desc" },
        new  { itemNo = 2, description = "desc2" }                  
    },
    test = new {
        a = new {
            b = new {
                something = "testing",
                someOtherThing = new {
                    aProperty = "1",
                    another = "2",
                    theThird = new {
                        bob = "quiteDeepNesting"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

return Json(bob, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

gives:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "orders": [
        {
            "itemNo": 1,
            "description": "desc"
        },
        {
            "itemNo": 2,
            "description": "desc2"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "a": {
            "b": {
                "something": "testing",
                "someOtherThing": {
                    "aProperty": "1",
                    "another": "2",
                    "theThird": {
                        "bob": "quiteDeepNesting"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is quite what i'm after, I dont know how many nested levels there will be when  make the call to the DB, Multiple objects , wtith potentially multiple objects

Comment: not checked the limits (if there are any but just opened an app where shipments have collections of items that have statuses with are all complex objects.  seems to run fine

Comment: well that works.. give it a go, if your using MVC 3 hopefully it will be a quick test

Comment: I should probably give a bit more info , I query the DB bringing back say a list of 10 items , each have unique ID's and a parent keys, I want to build my object and then serialize into JSON, I beleive the building of the object and assigning the correct kids to correct parents is where my issue lies

Comment: I guess my question really is , how do you create the complex c# objects in the first place ?

Comment: which part are you having trouble with: defining the classes, or building them from the data you get back from the DB?

Comment: I would recommend marking this answered then posting another question with your current code and stating where it falls short.. you could be using datareaders, table adapters, entity framework, nhibernate, too much details to slap on the end of a question about json serialisation. you rother question could include the JSON object structure that is your goal.

Comment: This is exactly what I’m after but curious can you loop through certain areas to dynamically added items into the []?

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

//Assumed code to connect to a DB and get data out using a Reader goes here

Object data = new {
    a = reader.GetString(field1),
    b = reader.GetString(field2),
    c = reader.GetString(field3)
};
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

This is built-in and saves you the work of serializing to JSON yourself!

This example assumes you are getting data from a database using some sort of reader, and it then constructs the object you want to serialize using an anonymous class.  Your anonymous class can be as simple or complex as you need it to be and the JavaScriptSerializer will handle transforming it to JSON.  This approach is also useful because you can easily control the JSON property names it will create in the JSON.

Comment: I should probably give a bit more info , I query the DB bringing back say a list of 10 items , each have unique ID's and a parent keys, I want to build my object and then serialize into JSON, I beleive the building of the object and assigning the correct kids to correct parents is where my issue lies

Comment: No problem--I've done the same myself in an app I worked on.  I took the result from the DB and used it to create an anonymous class which I then passed to the serialization method.  So for the "data" object above, you might construct it like this: new {a = reader.GetString(field1), b = reader.GetString(field2), c = reader.GetString(field3) };    Using an anonymous class declaration for the object you pass to the JavaScriptSerializer's Serialize method gives you easy control over what to include in the JSON and how it will be represented, without needing to create a named class.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
 


var strNJson = new
            {
                to = "hello",
                notification = new
                {
                    title = "textTitle",
                    body = "bodyText"
                }
            };
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(strNJson);
```

> 

```
{   "to":"hello",
       "notification": {
                        "title":"titleText",
                         "body":"bodyText"
                     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `ExpandoObject` under the `System.Dynamic` namespace.

Here is a small snippet for achieving your solution:

```
dynamic parameters = new dynamic[2];

parameters[0] = new ExpandoObject();
parameters[0].title = "Yes";
parameters[0].id = "1";

parameters[0].menu = new dynamic[1];
parameters[0].menu[0] = new ExpandoObject();

parameters[0].menu[0].title = "Maybe";
parameters[0].menu[0].id = "3";
parameters[0].menu[0].alert = "No";
parameters[0].menu[0].menu = new dynamic[1];
parameters[0].menu[0].menu[0] = new ExpandoObject();
parameters[0].menu[0].menu[0].title = "Maybe Not";
parameters[0].menu[0].menu[0].id = "8";
parameters[0].menu[0].menu[0].alert = "No";
parameters[0].menu[0].menu[0].menu = new dynamic[0];

parameters[1] = new ExpandoObject();
parameters[1].title = "No";
parameters[1].id = "2";
parameters[1].menu = new dynamic[0];


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

[Here is the work in fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/imrHR9)

**Note:**  There are other ways to achieve this, but I have been using this approach.