# How to make a nested json file from two datatables

Tags: c#

I want to get a nested json file like,

```
{
    "table": "table_name",
    "mode": "read",
    "data": [{
            "code": "123",
            "name": "name1",
            "place": "place_name1"
        }, {
            "code": "456",
            "name": "name2",
            "place": "place_name2"
        }, {
            "code": "789",
            "name": "name2",
            "place": "place_name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to retrieve one entire datatable to the datarow of another datatable.:( Seeking your help..

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create nested json with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354107/create-nested-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: dr["table"] = tableName.ToString();
           dr["mode"] = "read";
            dr["data"] = dtItemMaster.ToString();
            
            dtInfo.Rows.Add(dr);      ...          This is what i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have to table `table1` and `table2` and **`Objdb`** is your database **`Entities`** and both table have an relation like `id` or anything then you can do that like this

```
var ss = objdb.Table1.Where(x => x.Table1Id >= 0).ToList();
var tblList = ss.Select(x => new
{
tbl2 = objdb.Table2
  .Where(z => z.Table1Id == x.Table1Id)
   .Select(s => new
          {
           code= s.code,
           name= s.name,
           place= z.place
          }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: No relation between two table, one is database table and another is manually created. i want to add the datatable from database into the other.

Comment: i have given you idea how you can do that now you must try your data table logic what you are trying to do and i think then there must be any common column or condition you can use that or try to update your question so that i we can help you better thank you