# How to create a list with different object type from json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I would like to create a list of different object types (with the same parent) from a json.

I have some models

```
public class Quote
{
    public virtual ICollection<QuoteLine> QuoteLines { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteLine
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class A : QuoteLine
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class B : QuoteLine
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

A quote have a collection of QuoteLines which can be A or B typed

I can do something like this

```
Quote quote = new Quote{
    QuoteLines = new List<QuoteLine>{
        new A { Order = 1, PropertyA = "propA"},
        new B { Order = 2, PropertyB = "propB"},
    }
}
```

I want to do this in the other way
I have a Json like this (return from a HttpClient.GetAsync())

```
{"quoteLines":[
    {"order":1,"propertyA":"propA"},
    {"order":2,"propertyB":"propB"}
]}
```

when I deserialize it into Quote, I loose the children properties.
I understand it's because I have a collection typed QuoteLine so the children properties aren't deserialized. But I'm looking for a way to keep all informations.

The call I'm doing:

```
    public async Task<Quote> GetById(int id)
    {
        Quote quote = null;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new StringBuilder(controllerName).Append("/").Append(id).ToString());
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            quote = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Quote>();
        }

        return quote;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929105/9020340

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.net serialize/deserialize derived types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a better solution which doesn't expose namespace and app assembly in the json.

only in the client app.
I added a custom JsonConverter:

```
public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    where T : class
{
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }


    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        if (serializer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serializer");
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        T target = Create(objectType, jObject);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);
        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

For each entity which derived:

```
public class QuoteLineJsonConverter : JsonCreationConverter<QuoteLine>
{
    protected override QuoteLine Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        if (jObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("jObject");
        string discriminator = jObject.GetValue("Discriminator", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>();
        if (discriminator != null)
        {

            switch (discriminator)
            {
                case "A":
                    return new A();
                case "B":
                    return new B();
                default:
                    return new QuoteLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new QuoteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And I only need to add a data attribute to my model to fire the custom converter

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(QuoteLineJsonConverter))]
public class QuoteLine
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Be carreful with jquery ajax request, you need to send the data as Json to call the custom JsonConverter.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "myUrl",
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use TypeNameHandling in JsonSerializerSettings for the purpose.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quote,settings);
var resultobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quote>(resultJson,settings);
```

Verifying the Output

```
foreach(var item in resultobject.QuoteLines)
{
    switch(item)
    {
        case A itemA :
            Console.WriteLine($"Type A: {itemA.Order}, {itemA.PropertyA}");
            break;
        case B itemB :
            Console.WriteLine($"Type A: {itemB.Order}, {itemB.PropertyB}");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            break;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Type A: 1, propA
Type A: 2, propB
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ^^ My case is a little bit complex because the json is generated in a webAPI, I ll put my solution in the "question"

Answer (score -1):

If it is not obligatory to use this particular class hierarchy, I would suggest to keep only one class `QuoteLine`, put all fields inside it and get rid of classes A and B. So the code would look like this:

```
public class QuoteLine
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

This way fields that are not present in json would be null, and you could check them before usage.

Comment: That's I would like to avoid, I already use models for CRUD operations

Comment: The downside is that this class may become unmaintanable even if you have few concepts (that should not be together) to hold in it.