# Returning instance of resource class

Tags: c#

I have a method which return an instance of resource class, how can use the "using" statement to avoid resource leak?

```
public ResourceClass method()
    {
        return  new ResourceClass ();
    }
```

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Implement disposable pattern using `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: What is `ResourceClass`? This: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource?view=azure-dotnet ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning in the middle of a using block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662773/returning-in-the-middle-of-a-using-block)

Comment: ResourceClass is a class that implements IDisposable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a list with different object type from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54007364/how-to-create-a-list-with-different-object-type-from-json)

Answer (score 2):

You can relegate the responsibility of disposing it to your caller by declaring your using block around the entire usage of the resource

```
public ResourceClass method()
{
    return new ResourceClass();
}
```

then

```
using(var s = method())
{
   //do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as just utilising the `method` method to create the instance in your `using` statement:

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    using (ResourceClass Foo = method())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will only work of course if `ResourceClass` implements `IDisposable`.  Otherwise, your program won't compile.

Comment: How do you know ResourceClass implements `IDisposable`?

Comment: It won't compile if it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.